# Error when Updating a web part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am developping a web part that I can't update on the SharePoint server without deleting it in webpart gallery. Then, I run in power shell :

- Update-SPSolution ...
- Disable-SPFeature ...
- Enable-SPFeature ...

I tried to delete the web part in the gallery programmatically in the event receiver, but it causes SharePoint to fail :

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;

            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["Web Part Gallery"];

                // go through the items in reverse
                for (int i = list.ItemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    // format name to look like a feature name
                    string webpartName = list.Items[i].Name;

                    webpartName = webpartName.Substring(0, webpartName.IndexOf('.'));

                    // delete web parts that have been added
                    if (properties.Feature.Definition.DisplayName == webpartName)
                    {
                        list.Items[i].Delete();

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong ? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am coming back to share the solution.
Here is the correct code to delele the web part from the gallery when deactivating the feature :

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            int ItemID = -1;
            using (SPSite oSite = (SPSite)(properties.Feature.Parent))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Galerie de composants WebPart"];

                    if (oList == null)
                    {
                        // si SharePoint en anglais 
                        oList = oWeb.Lists["Web Part Gallery"];
                    }
                    // si oList == null, alors aucun de traitement
                    // on ne connais pas le nom de la liste 
                    // de la gallerie de web part
                    if (oList != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < oList.ItemCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (oList.Items[i].Title.Equals(WebPartTitle))
                            {
                                ItemID = oList.Items[i].ID;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ItemID != -1)
                        {
                            SPListItem oItem = oList.GetItemById(ItemID);
                            oItem.Delete();
                            oList.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //will throw to and error page
            throw new Exception(String.Format("The has been an error "
            + "removing the WebPart from the Gallery; {0}", e.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Finally, after adding this code in the event receiver, the procedure for updating the Web Part solution is :

- Disable-SPFeature ...
- Uninstall-SPFeature ...
- Update-SPSolution ...
- Install-SPFeature ...
- Enable-SPFeature ...

Hope it helps